# Flow of control_Mouse click events_OpenCV_Python

Tags: python, opencv, mouseclick-event

I wrote a program in Python using Open CV to draw small circles on a black image and join them with a line to test the use of mouse click events. However I do not understand the flow of control in the code. I got these 2 variations from 2 sources.

Please explain to me the flow of control in both of them.

First code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

x2,y2,c=0,0,0

def click (event,x,y,flags,param):
    global x2,y2,c
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 5, (0,0,255),-1) 
        if (c==0):
            cv2.imshow('image',img)
        else:
            cv2.line(img, (x2,y2), (x,y), (255,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.imshow('image',img)
        x2,y2=x,y
        c=c+1

img=np.zeros((700,700,3), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('image',img)

cv2.setMouseCallback('image',click)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Second code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

x2,y2,c=0,0,0

def click (event,x,y,flags,param):
    global x2,y2,c
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 5, (0,0,255),-1) 
        if (c!=0):
            cv2.line(img, (x2,y2), (x,y), (255,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        x2,y2=x,y
        c=c+1

img=np.zeros((700,700,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',click)

while (True):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20)==ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only differences in the code are:

```
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',click)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

in part 1, and

```
cv2.namedWindow('image') 
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',click)

while (True):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20)==ord('q'):
        break
```

in part 2.

Both codes set up a callback function `"cv2.setMouseCallback"`, and in part 1, an endless delay cv2.waitKey(0) is called following that, essentially pausing the main body while acquiring any callbacks. If you press any key, the program will continue flowing.

In part 2, a named window is set up - not necessary to do anything in particular. An infinite `while (True)` loop is set up to continuously check if a specific key has been pressed - in this case, 'q', which would break the program out of the loop. This loop also continuously invokes `cv2.imgshow` - which is redundant since the callback function calls `cv2.imgshow` after any changes. A loop like this is useful if you want to add additional keystrokes to check for - maybe 'r' to revert the image state to beginning, or anything else you might think of.

Comment: The callback function is outside the while loop in the second code. How does that function get called every time even though the flow of control enters the infinite while loop?

Also, I have edited the redundant imshow(). It was a carelessness on my part.

Comment: Callback function sets up a way for an even to trigger a function from outside the regular program flow. Therefore, your callback functions should be outside any loops unless you are setting up callback functions with different parameters using a loop.